# Best way to handle the returning of different error/success data from method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I wonder how do you handle the scenario of returning different errors/success data from a method.

I have tried different aproaches but I'm not satisfied with any of them. Mainly I have tried these 2 ones. In this example I show a user authentication service method I use in my application.

The method would be something like this (code is not really important just the error handling):

```
public async Task<UserServiceResult> AuthenticateAsync(string email, string password)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUser.Email))
            throw new ArgumentException("Email cannot be null or empty string", "email");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentException("Password cannot be null or empty string", "password");
        if(!EmailTools.IsValidEmail(newUser.Email))
            throw new ArgumentException("Email format is not valid.", "email");
        if (!PasswordTools.IsPasswordValid(password))
            throw new ArgumentException("Password is not valid. Email must have more than 10 chars a capital letter and a number", "password");


        ApplicationUser user = await _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == newUser.Email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;

            PasswordTools.CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);
            newUser.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            newUser.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;


            //Insert user
            _dbContext.Users.Add(newUser);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ValidUserResult(newUser);
        }
        else
            return new UserExistsResult();
}
```

And here the set of errors defined that are used in the previous method:

```
public enum ValidationStatus { UserNotFound, InvalidPassword, InvalidEmail, UserExists, Valid }

public abstract class UserServiceResult
{
    public ValidationStatus Status { get; private set; }
    protected UserServiceResult(ValidationStatus status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}

public class UserNotFoundResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public UserNotFoundResult() : base(ValidationStatus.UserNotFound) { }
}

public class InvalidPasswordResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public InvalidPasswordResult() : base(ValidationStatus.InvalidPassword) { }
}

public class InvalidEmailResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public InvalidEmailResult() : base(ValidationStatus.InvalidEmail) { }
}

public class UserExistsResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public UserExistsResult() : base(ValidationStatus.UserExists) { }
}


public class ValidAuthenticatedUserResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public AuthenticatedUser AuthenticatedUser {get; private set;}

    public ValidAuthenticatedUserResult(AuthenticatedUser user) : base(ValidationStatus.Valid)
    {
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("User can't be null");
        AuthenticatedUser = user;
    }
}

public class ValidUserResult : UserServiceResult
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; private set; }

    public ValidUserResult(ApplicationUser user) : base(ValidationStatus.Valid)
    {
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("User can't be null");
        User = user;
    }
}
```

I don't really disagree with this way of handling errors and success but there's something that  annoys me a lot and it is that if I want to access the ValidUserResult or ValidAuthenticatedUserResult data I must downcast the returning value (that is of type UserServiceResult) depending on the Status property checking if is ok or not. This seems really ugly to me.

I have tried another aproach is having all possible returned data in the base classe and get what I need depending on the calling context and if the the method call was a success or not. Something like this:

```
public enum ValidationStatus { UserNotFound, InvalidPassword, InvalidEmail, UserExists, Valid }

public abstract class UserServiceResult
{
    public ValidationStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public IAuthenticableUser User { get; private set; } 
    public string Token { get;}
    public DateTime Expiration { get;}
    public IUserService.UserScope Scope { get; }

    protected UserServiceResult(ValidationStatus status, IAuthenticableUser user=null, string token = null,DateTime expiration = default(DateTime), IUserService.UserScope scope = IUserService.UserScope.ClientApp)
    {
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("User can't be null");

        Status = status;
        User = user;
        Token = token;
        Scope = scope;
    }
}
```

This avoids the castings but seems a bit wonky. I need to have all possible returned data into one class which I don't like either :).

So, how do you handle this scenario?

Comment: Return a value that contains all information you need. Or return several values using a tuple or `out` parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "Return a value that contains all information you need"? Is it like the second example I showed?

Comment: It may for example be an instance of a class with several properties or a flag enum depending on your requirements.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there's no difference with my previous example (second one). In the end you will end up with a blob of properties delegating to the calling code the extraction of the correct data depending on the status value. Doesn't seem a clean solution to me :/.

Comment: This is a bit opinion based. But in cases like these I like to create a generic wrapper to wrap my results in. The wrapper will hold a success state, if applicable a result of it's generic type. And then you can add failed information however you like (maybe even as a second generic type for the wrapper). But the upside is that you seperate the actual result from the succes information.

Comment: @Notbad: I would say the idea of having a method return a variety is not very clean in the first place.

Comment: Agreed. I will have to rethink this a bit more. I liked the idea of the out params, but having an async method it is not possible. I will check the specialized error classes way a bit more. I think it is the way to go

Comment: Aside, this would be a good question for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)—and especially since you have working code. Generally, Stack Overflow shies away from opinion-based questions like “what is the best approach?” since they don’t lend themselves to a single, concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just boils down to not using a very robust "result" class. For example, I tend to use something like the following:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Success { get; }
    public string Error { get; private set; }

    public bool Failure => !Success;

    protected Result(bool success, string error)
    {
        Success = success;
        Error = error;
    }

    public static Result Fail(string message)
    {
        return new Result(false, message);
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail<T>(string message)
    {
        return new Result<T>(default(T), false, message);
    }

    public static Result Ok()
    {
        return new Result(true, string.Empty);
    }

    public static Result<T> Ok<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T>(value, true, string.Empty);
    }

    public static Result Combine(params Result[] results)
    {
        foreach (Result result in results)
        {
            if (result.Failure)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    protected internal Result(T value, bool success, string error)
        : base(success, error)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This lets you do stuff like:

```
return Result.Ok(foo);
```

Or:

```
return Result.Fail<Foo>("Error message here.");
```

For API responses, I use a modified version that accepts `ValidationProblemDetails` as the "error" instead of just a simple string. So, you can trick this out however you like.

Comment: This seems a solution that could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this problem by having another data construct in my class which will contain all the information that will be needed in the upper hand caller methods (you can `return`, or use `out` keyword, or just make it a `public` property depending on your case).
Then instead of `throw`, simply `return` and handle what you need in the upper hand caller.

Comment: What about having the method takie2 handles. One for error and another for success ?

Comment: In applications I coded for, having that would add unnecessary complications but my method would fit in overal integrity of my code, specially if you also want to add error codes.